# limit of sum of function over uncountable index set

Tags: limits

What would be the definition of such a limit,sum? Suppose I have a set of functions $(f_i)_{i\in \mathbb{R}}$ I know for every $i$, $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f_i(x)=0$. How is the sum $\sum_{i\in\mathbb{R}}f_i(x)$ definied and how could I show $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\sum_{i\in\mathbb{R}}f_i(x)=0$ ?

Comment: A sum is a discrete creature. The closest thing I can think of is a integral of the form $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_i(x) \ di$ for fixed $x$ (if that's even possible). Why do you want this?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any definition of summation over arbitrary indexing set that is widely accepted in the literature, but I have thought of this question before and have a possible definition that may be of use to you.

Suppose that $\mathcal G$ is an abelian topological group with underlying set $G$ and that $f: S \to G$ is a map from some (not necessarily finite) set $S$. Let $\mathcal Q(S)$ be the set of all finite subsets of $S$. $Q(S)$ forms a directed set under the relation of subset $\subseteq$. We will call this directed set $\mathbb Q(S)$. Here $\mathbb Q$ will not never stand for the set of rational numbers. Define the map $\eta: Q(S) \to G \ A \mapsto \sum_{a \in A}f_a$. Note now that $\eta$ is a [topoloical net](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_(mathematics)) over $\mathbb Q(S)$. Now, we can define $\sum_{s \in S}f_s$ to be the limit of $\eta$ if such a limit exists and is unqiue. Note that if $\mathcal G$ is not Hausdorff then $\eta$ may have multiple possible limits, in which case it would be better to codify $\sum_{s \in S}f_s$ to be the set of all such limits.

Furthermore, if $\mathcal G$ is an ordered topological group with ordering $\leq$ we can define what it means for $\sum_{s \in S}f_s$ to diverge to $+\infty$ and $-\infty$ respectively. We can say that $\sum_{s \in S}f_s$ diverges to $+\infty$ ($-\infty$) if $\eta$ eventually is strictly greater than (less than) every element of $G$. These conditions can be formalised by $(O1)$ and $(O2)$ respectively.

$$
\begin{align}
\forall x \in G \ \exists A \in Q(S) \ \forall B \in Q(S): A \subseteq B \implies \sum_{b \in B}f_b \gneq x \tag{O1}\\
\forall x \in G \ \exists A \in Q(S) \ \forall B \in Q(S): A \subseteq B \implies \sum_{b \in B}f_b \lneq x \tag{O2}
\end{align}
$$

The definition I have given is rather abstract, but can be reformulated easily in the case that $\mathcal G = (\mathbb R, +)$, which we now give:

For all $f: S \to \mathbb R$, we say that $\sum_{s \in S}f_s$ converges to the value $\nu$ if equation ($1$) is satisfied. In this case we set $\sum_{s \in S}f_s = \nu$.

$$\forall \epsilon \in \mathbb R^+ \  \exists A \in Q(S)\  \forall B \in Q(S): A \subseteq B \implies \left|\nu- \sum_{b \in B}f_b\right| < \epsilon \tag{1}$$

When $S = \mathbb N$, I believe that condition $(1)$ is equivalent to absolute convergence of the series $\sum_{s \in S}f_s$, but I would have to go back and check this to be sure. In you case you want $S = \mathbb R$.

---

For your second question of whether $\lim_{x \to 0}\sum_{i \in \mathbb R}f_i(x) = 0$ should $\sum_{i \in \mathbb R}f_i(x)$ exist for all $x$ in a neighbourhood of $0$ and for all $i \in \mathbb R$ that $\lim_{x \to 0}f_i(x) = 0$ I would recon the answer is that it depends. Note that one is trying interchange a limit and a summation. In general this is not possible without a further hypothesis on the convergence of the sum.

Comment: I've just realised my proposal has a a flaw that means it does not produce the correct answer for some topological spaces. I have a fix but my answer won't be refactored for a couple of days!

Comment: After some thought I have come to the conclusion that my proposal should work fine for topological groups,. I may make a new answer at some point with a better definition. Meanwhile I will edit this answer with a couple of tweaks for readability.

Answer (score 2):

An uncountable sum of positive numbers is always infinite. There’s some $\epsilon$ so that an infinite number of them are at least $\epsilon$, otherwise the number of numbers would be countable. Adding infinitely many numbers with a positive lower bound  is unbounded.

There are some ways of salvaging this. It might makes sense if only a countable number of the $f_i$ are nonzero. Alternatively, you could try taking an integral if you consider $f$ as a function over two variables.